# how can I access the method in a subclass through my parent reference variables?

Tags: java

suppose you have

```
public class A{
   public void a_parent(){
    System.out.println("Parent class invoked:");
   }
}
```

as your main class and 4 other classes inherit that class

```
public class A1 extends A{
   public void a1(){
       System.out.println("a1 class invoked:");
   }
```

}

```
public class A2 extends A{
   public void a2(){
       System.out.println("a2 class invoked:");
   }
```

}

```
public class A3 extends A{
   public void a3(){
       System.out.println("a3 class invoked:");
   }
```

}

```
public class A4 extends A{
   public void a4(){
       System.out.println("a4 class invoked:");
   }
}
```

in the main method, I call them like this.

```
 public class TestClasses{
   public static void main(String args[]){
     A a;
        a = new A1();
        a = new A2();
        a = new A3();
        a = new A4();

System.out.println(a.a2());
  }
}
```

when I try to invoke the a2 method, I can't. I only have access to a4 and a_parent method.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: You want the variable `a` to remember its previous values??? `a` has the value of `new A4();`, it has absolutely nothing to do with `A2`. And I doubt you even have access to `a4` since `a` is of type `A` which does not have a method of that name.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, after you assign `a = new A2();` you do `a = new A3()` so a isn't even an instance of A2 anymore.

Secondly, a can be any instance of A, it doesn't know for sure that at that point it's going to be of A2. Therefore you should check this and do a cast:

```
if(a instanceof A2){
    A2 a2 = (A2) a;
    System.out.println(a2.a2());
}
```

In your code, this won't do anything, because a isn't actually an instance of A2, but i hope you get my point.